# Microsoft Access Reusing Record ID's

Tags: ms-access

I have a (Microsoft access office 365 database). I have a number of records in a table in the database. Lets say I have 5 records numbered 1 to 5 respectfully. now when I delete record number 3. Record number 3 is now gone. The problem I am having is when I create a new record I see that record number 3 is being used again as a record number despite the fact that record number 3 has been deleted. This to me should not be happening. I recently upgraded the Microsoft Access Database Engine redistributable 2016 on our server from 2010. Thinking this might resolve the problem. The data type and primary key for the archiveID field is AutoNumber.

Please advise.

Comment: Of course that shouldn't happen! Any data-macros?

Comment: `The data type and primary key for the archiveID field is AutoNumber.` It it's really autonumber, that should **not** happen in any case, as far as I know. Are you sure it is Autonumber? Also, as @ComputerVersteher said, is there any macro or VBA code or something that might be interfering with that?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns assuming the OP operates on table level no macro or vba is executed. Only a database trigger (data-macro) can interfer there.

Answer (score 0):

Some times `AutoNumber` can be damaged, for example by manual assignment. Try to repair it:

```sql
INSERT INTO [TableName]([archiveID]) SELECT MAX([archiveID]) FROM [TableName];
```

And check if problem repeats.

Comment: `AutoNumber` field remember its last inserted value. And if you assign it manually to N it will generate N+1 next time. May be your `AutoNumber` has been broken somehow similar. And SQL command above will fix current AutoNumber's value.

Comment: I am not sure what to do with your answer 4dmonster. I have an archive table with approx. 500 records. Do I run the above SQL statement on this prepopulated table? I'm not creating a new table here am I?

Comment: This works even the query will fail (pk key violation)? You can try`ALTER TABLE [TableName] ALTER COLUMN archiveID AUTOINCREMENT(1001,1)`what set the autoincrement to 1001.

Comment: I am not sure how to apply the above SQL statement. The table I have with my data is called archive. The primary key is called archiveID. Do run I the above SQL statement on the archive table? Do I substitute the TableName with archive?

Comment: Yes replace the`TableName`with the real table name (square-brackets can be omited if table name contains no special chars (only Letters and Numbers and`_`(underscore)).